# Is there a general way of converting a hash into an two-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

The way a hash is structed can always vary, it can be a hash of a hash of an array or whatever.
And for every different struct of a hash there needs to be a different implementation of turning it into a two dimensional array.

Is there a general way of converting a hash into an array?
Such that i could say, for instance, first key becomes column 0, second key column 1 etc.

**Example from comments:**

`$distangle{some_distance}{some_angle}=();`
now I want to convert that hash of hashes into an ordinary two dimensional array `@distangle=(some_distance,some_angle)`.
That's a method, then tomorrow I have some different form of a hash I also need to convert to a two dimensional array.

Comment: How do *keys* "become" *columns*? Your problem is not well defined. Are you talking about a *grid*?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? There's probably a better way to do it. Always start with what you are trying to accomplish rather than how you think you should do it. See the Perlmonks writeup on [XY Problems](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Comment: @axeman:hash is one way of storing information, array is another. so when i convert the hash then its keys are a part of the information, so i put it in the array. im talking about two dimensional arrays.

Comment: @brian
im trying to be able to convert miscellaneous types of hashes into two dimensional arrays using a single solution.

Comment: No, that's your solution. I want to know what your problem is. What is your starting state and your desired end state? Forget about what you think the solution is and just explain the task.

Answer (score 0):

What is "first" key in a hash? The keys are not ordered. Do you want to order them alphabetically?

```
@arr = map { $hash{$key} } sort keys %hash;
```

**EDIT**:

OP wants a 2D array, so here it is:

```
@arr = ()
for $first (keys %hash) {
    for $second (keys %{ $hash{$first} }) {
        for $third (keys %{ $hash{$first}{$second} }) {
            my $value = $hash{$first}{$second}{$third};
            push @arr, ($first, $second, $third, $value);
```

Something like this?

**EDIT 2**: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762399/sort-by-value-hash-of-hash-of-hashes-perl/763080#763080) looks nice too.

Comment: $cars{type}{color}{number}=155; in this one, 'type' is the first key.

Comment: Should use curly bracer to get value by key `$hash{$key}` in hash.

Comment: no two dimensional, that was just to demonstrate what i mean by first key.

Comment: @Hermann What array do you want to get from `$cars{type}{color}{number}` ? And what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i have all kinds of different hashes, and im routinely converting them all to two dimensional arrays, and consequently im doing the same thing multiple times.

Comment: $distangle{some_distance}{some_angle}=(); now i want to convert that hash of hashes into an ordinary two dimensional array @distangle=(some_distance,some_angle). that's a method, then tomorrow i have some different form of a hash i also need to convert to a two dimensional array.

Comment: regarding edit of current answer, no im talking about a single method with which i can convert a hash of any sort into a two dimensional array, that method given would work with a hash of hash of hash of elements, but not hash of arrays or hash of hashes or.. all the other ones.

Comment: @eumiro `@arr = []` will create array with `[]` as element in it. I guess you need `@arr = ()` instead.

Comment: @Hermann - the second edit gives you a link to a nice solution. Wasn't it shown to you as you posted your original question?

Comment: it may well have,i find the user interface very lacking in readability and simplicity though, but it's in the direction. the solution is off course, a recursive one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, hashes are unordered, so when you say the "first key", there's no such thing.

Secondly, if you do have a hash of hash of arrays (as in your example), then it seems to me that the strict requirement of reducing it to a 2-dimensional array will result in data-loss (assuming you mean that none of the elements in that array can be hashrefs or arrayrefs).

Comment: $cars{type}{color}{number}=155; in this one, 'type' is the first key. Yes data loosing is an issue when converting like this.

Comment: Ah ok. The example you've posted helps explain things.